# Safely rename a namespace of a specific project in a solution in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, namespaces

In, Visual Studio 2010, I have a solution with various projects and I have two projects that share a C# namespace with the same name, however, they are intended to be separate namespaces.

I want to rename both namespaces to different ones to prevent confusion. However, I wonder if there is a safer solution other than having to use Ctrl+H and choosing to replace all the occurences in the project.

I know you can just retype the name of a namespace in code and VS will ask to you if you want to rename all occurences, however I don't know if VS will be smart doing this to each project separately, and it says if I rename it I cannot undo the action because it will be applied to too many files. I also tried to open a project alone to prevent this but VS automatically opens the whole solution.

Comment: Yokoelf please see the posted answers and mark as answer, vote up or comment if they dont provide enough information

Answer (score 0):

You can use a refactoring tool such as [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to do this safely.
There are also other tools available, but I usually use this because it works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Copy the folder that contains your solution, and projects, to another folder (just in case)**

Create a new solution with just **projectOne** inside and perform the refactor of that namespace there.

Create **another** new soution with just **projectTwo** inside and perform the refactor of that namespace there.

Open the original solution, thas has those two projects inside, and see if the results are what you expected

Answer (score 0):

You can load the projects one at a time and refactor the namespaces as you wish. Open the entire solution and unload one of the two projects.

If you want advanced refactoring, you can try DevExpress' [Refactor Pro](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1C5390EF-48A5-487C-9332-29B98EFECC22) or [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Both are awesome refactoring tools.